# Unable to use dimensions with WMTS

Tags: geoserver, wmts, image-mosaic, dimensions

I am setting up an image mosaic in GeoServer and I can't seem to figure out how to get custom dimensions to work with WMTS. My WMS requests work well when I include custom dimension parameters, but WMTS ignores them and always assumes the default value. In GetCapabilities for WMS, I can see all of the potential choices for each dimension (as expected) but in GetCapabilities for WMTS, the dimensions do not appear.

Here is an example of the resource URL for WMTS:

```
<ResourceURL format="image/png" resourceType="tile" template="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/testWorkspace:geotiffLayer/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/png"/>
```

Based on [this documentation](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/wmts.html#tile-resources), I would have expected my custom dimension to be append-able to the request. Even when I try a WMTS request with a dimension value specified, it doesn't change the result. Here is an example of a WMTS request where the included dimension is ignored:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/testWorkspace:geotiffLayer/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:4/4/8?format=image/png&DIM_RUNTIME_FORECAST=1001
```

I've also tried several similar requests (without the "DIM_" prefix, etc.) but no luck.

However, here is the same layer in WMS GetCapabilities:

```
    <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
    <Name>testWorkspace:geotiffLayer</Name>
    <Title>geotiffLayer</Title>
    <Abstract/>
    <KeywordList>
    <Keyword>geotiff10</Keyword>
    <Keyword>WCS</Keyword>
    <Keyword>ImageMosaic</Keyword>
    </KeywordList>
    <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
    <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
    <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    <westBoundLongitude>-125.0</westBoundLongitude>
    <eastBoundLongitude>-70.0</eastBoundLongitude>
    <southBoundLatitude>25.0</southBoundLatitude>
    <northBoundLatitude>55.0</northBoundLatitude>
    </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-125.0" miny="25.0" maxx="-70.0" maxy="55.0"/>
    <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="25.0" miny="-125.0" maxx="55.0" maxy="-70.0"/>
    <Dimension name="RUNTIME_FORECAST" default="1002" units="">1001,1002</Dimension>
```

You can see the dimension "RUNTIME_FORECAST" appears as expected, and when I add DIM_RUNTIME_FORECAST=1001 to a request, it returns the result I expect.

As background, I used an indexer.xml and associated config files to set up the mosaic and it connects to a PostGIS database for storage. This particular mosaic just uses GeoTIFFs, but I have another one using NetCDF files and it has the same issue. The database has the custom dimension populated as expected.

Is there something special I need to do to activate custom dimensions for WMTS?

I should also note that I tried the ["WMTS Multidimensional" plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/wmts-multidimensional/index.html). That showed the dimensions in GetCapabilities (though not in the resource URL), but the requests still ignored the custom dimension.

This behavior has occurred in versions 2.20.4 and 2.21.0 of GeoServer.

EDIT: Here is the GeoServer log after submitting a WMTS GetTile request:

```
2022-07-20 14:01:59,743 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/web/**'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,743 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/rest/**'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001'; against '/**'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Request matched by universal pattern '/**'
2022-07-20 14:01:59,744 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /testWorkspace/gwc/service/wmts, QueryString: SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&tileMatrixSet=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetTile&tileRow=4&tileCol=8&tileMatrix=EPSG:4326:4&LAYER=geotiffLayer&DIM_runtime_forecast=1001 with /**
2022-07-20 14:01:59,760 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named testWorkspace:gwc
2022-07-20 14:01:59,760 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@bb086f0] and 1 interceptors
2022-07-20 14:01:59,761 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not lookup context testWorkspace as a layer, trying as group
2022-07-20 14:01:59,761 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not lookup context testWorkspace as a group either
2022-07-20 14:01:59,763 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.gwc.wmts.WMTSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:01:59,764 DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc.layer] - --> http-nio-8080-exec-6 submitting getMap request for meta grid location [8, 8, 4] on org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerMetaTile@43f2dfdd
2022-07-20 14:01:59,765 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:01:59,765 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2022-07-20 14:01:59,766 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2022-07-20 14:01:59,766 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing raster style for testWorkspace:geotiffLayer
2022-07-20 14:01:59,768 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:01:59,768 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up map
2022-07-20 14:01:59,770 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up 512x1024 image
2022-07-20 14:01:59,770 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:01:59,793 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Direct rendering path produced the following image chain:
JAI op: Mosaic(it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic.MosaicOpImage) at Level: 0, offset:0, 0, size:512 x 1024, tile size:456 x 456
Params. Parameter 1:MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY; Parameter 2:null; Parameter 3:[javax.media.jai.ROIShape@73a9ed8b]; Parameter 4:[[0.0]]; Parameter 5:[255.0, 0.0]; Parameter 6:[RangeDouble[-Infinity, 0.0)]; 
Bands: 2, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Translucent
Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
Number of sources: 1
   JAI op: BandMerge(it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandmerge.BandMergeOpImage) at Level: 1, offset:-1, -1, size:456 x 456, tile size:456 x 456
   Params. Parameter 1:[null, null]; Parameter 2:0.0; Parameter 3:null; Parameter 4:null; Parameter 5:true; 
   Bands: 2, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Translucent
   Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
   Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
   Number of sources: 2
      JAI op: Crop(it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop.CropOpImage) at Level: 2, offset:-1, -1, size:456 x 456, tile size:475 x 475
      Params. Parameter 1:-1.0; Parameter 2:-1.0; Parameter 3:456.0; Parameter 4:456.0; Parameter 5:null; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:[0.0]; 
      Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
      Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
      Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
      Number of sources: 1
         JAI op: Scale(it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale.ScaleBilinearOpImage) at Level: 3, offset:-20, -20, size:475 x 475, tile size:475 x 475
         Params. Parameter 1:0.8343704; Parameter 2:0.68266666; Parameter 3:-19.64563; Parameter 4:-19.683556; Parameter 5:InterpolationBilinear; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:false; Parameter 8:null; Parameter 9:null; 
         Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
         Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
         Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
         Number of sources: 1
            JAI op: Mosaic(it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic.MosaicOpImage) at Level: 4, offset:0, 0, size:569 x 696, tile size:512 x 512
            Params. Parameter 1:MOSAIC_TYPE_OVERLAY; Parameter 2:null; Parameter 3:null; Parameter 4:[[0.0]]; Parameter 5:[0.0]; Parameter 6:[RangeDouble[-Infinity, 0.0)]; 
            Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
            Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
            Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
            Number of sources: 1
               JAI op: Scale(it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale.ScaleBilinearOpImage) at Level: 5, offset:-1, -1, size:570 x 696, tile size:512 x 512
               Params. Parameter 1:1.0; Parameter 2:0.99928266; Parameter 3:-1.0; Parameter 4:-1.0; Parameter 5:InterpolationBilinear; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:false; Parameter 8:null; Parameter 9:null; 
               Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
               Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
               Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
               Number of sources: 1
                  JAI op: ImageRead(com.sun.media.jai.imageioimpl.ImageReadOpImage) at Level: 6, offset:0, 0, size:570 x 697, tile size:512 x 512
                  Params. Parameter 1:FileImageInputStreamExtImpl which points to /var/geoserver/datadir/data/geotiffLayer/secondFile_1002.tif; Parameter 2:0; Parameter 3:false; Parameter 4:false; Parameter 5:false; Parameter 6:null; Parameter 7:null; Parameter 8:[class it.geosolutions.imageio.imageioimpl.EnhancedImageReadParam    SourceRegion(Rectangle)[x:1860, y:607, width:1140, height:1393]     SourceSubsampling[ssx:2, ssy:2]     DestinationOffset(Point)[x:0, y:0]]; Parameter 9:it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader@2fb81854; 
                  Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
                  Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
                  Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
                  Number of sources: 0
      JAI op: Constant(com.sun.media.jai.opimage.ConstantOpImage) at Level: 2, offset:-1, -1, size:456 x 456, tile size:475 x 475
      Params. width:456.0; height:456.0; bandValues:[-1]; 
      Bands: 1, type: Byte; Color model:class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel, transparency: Opaque
      Tile cache: it.geosolutions.concurrent.ConcurrentTileCacheMultiMap@2f182072
      Tile scheduler: com.sun.media.jai.util.SunTileScheduler@2883c115<global>, parallelism 7, priority 5
      Number of sources: 0
2022-07-20 14:01:59,794 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:76)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:41)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor364.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:869)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1350)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:690)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:610)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:555)
    at org.geowebcache.util.ResponseUtils.writeTile(ResponseUtils.java:100)
    at org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher.handleServiceRequest(GeoWebCacheDispatcher.java:408)
    at org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher.handleRequestInternal(GeoWebCacheDispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.dispatch.GwcServiceProxy.dispatch(GwcServiceProxy.java:80)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor325.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:869)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-07-20 14:02:00,258 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2022-07-20 14:02:00,258 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:02:00,263 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2022-07-20 14:02:00,264 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2022-07-20 14:02:00,264 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:02:00,268 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2022-07-20 14:02:00,268 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2022-07-20 14:02:00,268 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:02:00,272 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2022-07-20 14:02:00,273 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2022-07-20 14:02:00,274 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[testWorkspace], available services were [WFSInfoImpl[WFS], WMSInfoImpl[WMS], WMTSInfoImpl[WMTS], WCSInfoImpl[WCS]]
2022-07-20 14:02:00,278 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2022-07-20 14:02:00,279 DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc] - Using cacheAgeMax {0}
2022-07-20 14:02:00,280 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
2022-07-20 14:02:00,281 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Edit 2: I've also tried this with a standard dimension (time) and experience the same behavior. A WMS query with the dimension works as expected, but WMTS ignores the time value I send.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @IanTurton thanks! Just added the log to my question.

Comment: @IanTurton you may have answered a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343413/geoserver-geowebcache-with-imagemosaic) in the past. Does GeoServer WMTS require that dimensions are manually added as parameter filters? I have not added parameter filters for my dimensions.

Comment: I think so, it's been a long time since I used that functionality